# Correlation between point feature (disease) and elevation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, dem, correlation

I have a problem! How can I calculate the correlation between point feature and Dem raster?

Hypothesis: disease prevalence in high altitude is more than low altitude.
I must do this in ArcGIS 10 and classify the altitude to 15 or 20 classes.

For example 0-200 meter above sea-level, 200-400 m and ... . I will join these altitude classes with disease prevalence shapefiles and then calculate the correlation between two entities. When I look at the layers, I see the correlation between altitude and disease.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Howeever, as it stands I think your question is too broad and that to make it OK for our focussed Q&A format we will need you to edit it with some details of what you have found in your initial research into looking for suitable techniques.

Comment: How is your disease data presented? Point per disease occurance or in attribute table?

Comment: Because you asked the same question about disease prevalence and [distance to volcanoes](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109190), it would appear you wish to conduct a multiple regression of disease prevalence against potential explanatory factors such as distances to volcanoes, elevations, and so on. Use the GIS to extract the elevation and distance information--those methods are amply explained in other threads--and use a statistical regression program to carry out the analysis. Extract the data as they are rather than classifying them, which loses information.

Comment: disease data presented in point format. i specified x,y for each patients resident location.

Comment: As whuber said extract and use explanatory regression. ArcGis has all the necessary tools in Spatial statistics tools.

Comment: excuse me. I cant do that!. Can you describe this method? i am not professional in ArcGIS. thank you.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.