# Finding correlation between point location and raster value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, spatial-analyst, correlation

I have what I thought was a very simple problem but I think I may have over thought it...

I have a population density raster and a point feature layer showing the locations of X (about 70 points).

All I simply want to do is a spatial correlation; do the instances of X tend to all occur in raster cells of higher pop density? no correlation? etc. purely locational. (The points have many attributes that I could begin to do multivariate regressions on but I don't want to at this stage).

I have tried autocorrelation (Morans etc. in ArcGIS), turning X into a Boolean raster and running band statistics in ArcGIS, Geographically Weighted Regression and I'm now onto Bivariate Spatial Association.

Someone tell me I've had a massive oversight?! Perhaps plotting the raster cell values against a Boolean 1 or 0 of the variable X?

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109187/correlation-between-point-feature-disease-and-elevation) question is similar but fizzled out while [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110455/correlation-between-a-raster-and-a-point-dataset) person looked like they want to test an interpolation. Don't mind answers in Arc and/or R.

Comment: Can you use the extract by points function in ArcGIS, to get the values of the rasters cells for all of your points and then use some other software, such as R, Matlab or Python to run a correlation test?

Comment: @ F_Kellner  That was my 1st thought, just get the data from the raster layer and extract it onto the point data. But then how would a correlation test know the range of values available on the raster? how could it tell the points all fell in, for e.g., the top quartile of pop density? or top 50%? or all within a very narrow band?

Comment: Ignore my answer below, I had misread your question, really.

Comment: Sounds like you have a stronger stats background than me, but can't you just extract the values (a list of population density values) and t-test them against the mean population density? It doesn't seem like you need a spatial solution (e.g. do points in the North correspond more closely with high population density than those in the South?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to test sample variation. That is to say, how well your sample distribution matches your population (raster) distribution. This is not a correlative relationship and is commonly done by comparing the sample mean and variance against the population.

Here is an example where I calculate mean, variance and quantiles for a random sample and the raster. I also plot the sample and population distributions.

First, for an example, we create a raster and take a random sample. I am simulating a very skewed distribution for the raster to add potential bias to the sample variation.

```
require(raster)
  sigma = 0.6; mu = 2
r <- raster(ncol=500, nrow=500)
  r[] <- dlnorm(seq(-10, 60, length.out = ncell(r)), mu, sigma) * 100

n <- 20 
  s <- sampleRandom(r, n, na.rm=TRUE, sp=TRUE) 
    s@data <- data.frame(s@data, r=extract(r, s))
      head(s@data)

plot(r)
  plot(s, pch=20, add=TRUE, col="black")
```

We can now calculate distributional moments for the sample and population.

```
# raster (population) mean, varaince and quantiles 
( rmean <- cellStats(r, stat="mean", na.rm=TRUE, asSample=FALSE) )  
( rvar <- cellStats(r, stat="sd", na.rm=TRUE, asSample=FALSE)^2 )     
( rquant <- quantile(r, probs = c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75)) )

# random points (sample) mean, varaince and quantiles 
( smean <- mean(s@data[,"r"]) )
( svar <- var(s@data[,"r"]) )
( squant <- quantile(s@data[,"r"], probs = c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75)) )
```

We can also plot the population and sample distributions. To test the null hypothesis that x and y were drawn from the same continuous distribution, by comparing distributions, we could perform a nonparametric two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test using the ks.test function.

```
# Plot sample and population distributions
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
  density(r, xlim=c(cellStats(r, "min"),cellStats(r, "max")), 
          main="Population distribution")
  plot(density(s@data[,"r"]), xlim=c(cellStats(r, "min"),cellStats(r, "max")),
       main="sample distribution")
```

A two-sample student t-test can easily be calculated by coercing the raster into a vector however, this is not memory safe and can be dangerous. I would recommend taking a very large random sample to represent the population.

```
r <- as.vector(as.matrix(r))
  r <- na.omit(r)      
    t.test(s@data[,"r"], y = r)
```

Because it sounds like you have a binominal response, you really should test the sample variation in an ANOVA or MANOVA framework so you can make sure that you have not only captured the population variation but also that the problem is balanced (variation equally split between [0,1]).

You may want to seriously consider a Bootstrap or Monte Carlo approach to identify bias. Since you are using a density raster, bandwidth and Kernel distribution can radically effect the estimates. You can quantify this uncertainty with these two methods.

Comment: These look like good ideas, but there are important issues to consider first. How were the point locations selected? They probably are not a simple random sample of the area. Understanding the basis of point selection is key to going forward. We also need to know their spatial supports. There are technical issues. The raster seems like it's not raw data, but may be a density or interpolated. That calls into question almost any parametric test (like the Student t). Resampling tests look much more promising--but require a clear model of the point selection process.

Comment: @whuber, I completely agree! Probabilistically, the sample bias is not accounted for, particularly in my "skewed" example. Even a nonparametric test (e.g., Kolmogorov-Smirnov) will miss spatial bias underlying the sample. I just wanted to distill this question to its simplest form and provide some exploratory analysis approaches. However, this is more than what most graduate students do in exploratory analysis. Missing spatial process, sample variation and bias are common reasons that students end up in my office, often after they have collected their data.

Comment: @Jeffrey, no my point data is not random, they are construction sites (bias). I want to know if their physical location has any relationship with the popn density raster below. The raster is 'real' data (rasterized census Output Areas), not interpolated, and the points have no inherent density info aside from what can be extracted from the raster cell beneath. I think you're right when you say i need to look at the sample variation, ie the variation of the density values where the point data lies. I think I approached slightly incorrectly. I'll hold off clicking 'answer' just for now.

Comment: Two approaches you could take would be: 1) a binominal model, in much the same way you would implement a species distribution model, with randomized null's or 2) a point pattern analysis, where you would test if your observed spatial process is significant from random. It would be easy to expand this type of analysis into a formalized Poisson point process model.